# How to remove item in list with WriteBatch?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud database. I queried a collection and got a list of documents. Each document contains a field `cars` which contains strings. In case the array contains at least three strings I want to remove the string `carPath` from this array (not the whole array). Otherwise, it should remove the whole document. I'm using WriteBatch. What I did:

```
fireDB.document(groupPath).collection("users").whereArrayContains("cars",carPath).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DocumentSnapshot curr : snapshot.getDocuments()) {
                List<String> cars = (List<String>) curr.get("cars");
                if (cars == null) continue;
                if (cars.size() <= 2) {
                    batch.delete(snapshot.getReference());
                } else {
                    // What to do here?
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How should I remove one item in the list with WriteBatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is just a [document update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).  You can do a regular update with [FieldValue.arrayRemove()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).  Except you will do it in the context of a batch using [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch#update(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) instead of a standalone update.

```
batch.update(snapshot.getReference(), "cars", FieldValue.arrayRemove(carPath));
```

Comment: Thanks! What will happen if `carPath` is not in `cars`?

Comment: I see, another small question if I may. If `carPath` is of type `String` but `cars` contains `DocumentReferences` (instaed of Strings) and one of the references has a path `carPath`. Is there a way to do something similar with `FieldValue`?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately so it's more easily searchable  for people who have that same question.