# How to remove a Document Reference in list with WriteBatch?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud database. This question is similar to the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892468/how-to-remove-item-in-list-with-writebatch/63892552#63892552) but now I'm interested in `DocumentReferences`. I queried a collection and got a list of documents. Each document contains a field `cars` which contains `DocumentReferences`. Each `DocumentReference` references a document that represents a car. Given the `carsPath` which is a path to the car document, I want to remove the `DocumentReferences` in that list. I'm using `WriteBatch`. If `cars` would contain just the paths, it would be easy by using:

```
batch.update(snapshot.getReference(), "cars", FieldValue.arrayRemove(carPath));
```

Is there a way to do something similar if we have `DocumentReferences` instead of `Strings`?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass DocumentReference object instead of a string to `FieldValue.arrayRemove()`.  The path of the reference must match exactly what's in the array.

Comment: What do you mean here by DocumentReference? How to do it with `carPath`? Is it `FieldValue.arrayRemove(fireDB.document(carPath))`?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do to build a DocumentReference type object. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference

Comment: @Doug: That's good advice. I encourage you to post this comment as an answer.